# Нужно ли перезагружать Nginx после обновление SSL сертификатов?

Tags: nginx, unix, centos, letsencrypt, certbot

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста после обновления сертификатов нужно ли перезагружать Nginx.

Система: CentOS, Nginx 1.14.0 + PHP-FPM
Сертификаты от lets-encrypt

В [мануале](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-nginx) простая задача для cron

```
0 0,12 * * * python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && certbot renew
```

Без перезагрузки, и reload, хотя в просторах интернета в разных манах указывается по разному. Как быть?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247418/do-i-need-to-restart-nginx-if-i-renew-my-security-certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша команда сертификат обновляет, нужно ещё в nginx конфиг перезагружать.

```
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew --renew-hook "/etc/init.d/nginx reload"
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, а не `--post-hook`, просто параметра `--renew-hook` в мануале не нашел